# Button is white instead of black inside of my expanded

Tags: flutter, colors

I'm trying to design my custom view and there's one thing that's not clear to me, when I try to pass my button with a white background, I get a black color and I don't understand why, everyone can explain it to me?

my code :

```
Expanded(
  flex: 3,
  child: Container(
    color: this.backgroundColorBox,
    child: Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Center(
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
              this.iconPath,
              color: Colors.white,
              height: 150,
              width: 150,
            ),
          ),
          flex: 2,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: Text(
                    this.textBox,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 25,
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 35, 63, 0.5)
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                ButtonTheme(
                    minWidth: 180,
                    height: 50,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      color: this.backgroundColorButton,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        this.textButton,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 25,
                          color: this.textColorButton
                        ),
                      ),
                      onPressed: null,
                    ),
                  )
              ]
            ),
          ),
          flex: 2,
        ),
      ]
    ),
  )
);
```

What is the real problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whenever you leave the `onPressed` property as `null` the button will be in `disabled` state so you should provide a function to your button `onPressed` property to see it in it's active state.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the color inside ButtonTheme also with parameter "buttonColor" as Colors.white.

Comment: no its' same and actually for my parent widget if i defined a button out of my row buttons are always black instead of white